# Multiple magento sites running under different users in nginx

Tags: nginx, magento

I have written a script that copies magento files and database from our production server and tries to configure it on a subdomain on our testing server.

Each testing site has:
- unique subdomain
- running under unique user specified in php-fpm pool

Here is the php-fpm pool config:

```
[test1]
user = test1
group = test1
listen = /run/php/php7.0-test1-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

So I would set up subsequent sites under different users like so:

```
[test2]
user = test2
group = test2
listen = /run/php/php7.0-test2-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

The problem comes when I try to duplicate the magento nginx server block (abbreviated version pasted below):

```
 upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  unix:/run/php-fpm/php-test1-fpm.sock;
 }

 server {

     listen 80;
     server_name test1.magento-dev.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/test1;
     include /usr/share/nginx/html/test1/nginx.conf.sample;
 }
```

If I duplicate the config like so:

```
 upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  unix:/run/php-fpm/php-test2-fpm.sock;
 }

 server {

     listen 80;
     server_name test2.magento-dev.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/test2;
     include /usr/share/nginx/html/test2/nginx.conf.sample;
 }
```

I get error because the fastcgi_backend upsteam is already defined.  I read the nginx documentation for upstream and it says it is a pool of servers but I don't really understand what is going on here to specify upstream like this to handoff php requests.

What am I doing wrong?  How should I setup multiple magento sites on subdomains running under different users?

How I fixed it:

I renamed the upstream but I didn't realise that the upstream name is used in proxy_pass.  You have to edit the proxy_pass in nginx.conf.sample in magento root.

Comment: You can't have two `upstream`s with the same name. Use a different name.

Comment: I tried that but then I get error there is exception but it doesn't have permission to write to log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I set up multiple pools using Nginx and PHP 5.6. I don't use paths, I use sockets. I've slightly edited my files to make them more generic, so if anything doesn't match assume it's a typo.

**/etc/php-fpm-5.6.d/pool1**

```
[pool1]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

**/etc/php-fpm-5.6.d/pool2**

```
[pool2]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

**/etc/nginx/upstreams.conf**

```
upstream php56-pool1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

upstream php56-pool2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

Here are relevant parts of my Nginx location blocks.

**/etc/nginx/site1.conf**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   php56-pool1;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/site2.conf**

```
location ~ php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php56-pool2;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```